# How to translate local point of DisplayObject?

Tags: flash, actionscript

There are some scenarios where we need to translate a local point in a displayObject to its parent.
When the displayObject is not rotated or scaled, the result is calculated easily:

```
var xAtParent:Number= displayObject.x+ localX; 
var yAtParent:Number= displayObject.y+ localY;
// where localX& localY are with respect to displayObject
```

But, when the displayObject is rotated or scaled, its not directly calculated, so the question is, Is there out of the box solution in action script 3 to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's built on a display list with affine ([Matrix](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Matrix.html)) transforms, Flash provides easy-to-use coordinate space transformation functions.  To go from `src` coordinate system to `dst` coordinate system (assuming both `src` and `dst` are `DisplayObject`s on the stage):

```
var p:Point = new Point(src_local_x, src_local_y);
p = src.localToGlobal(p);
p = dst.globalToLocal(p);
// p.x is dst_local_x
// p.y is dst_local_y
```

You can also easily get the bounds of any `src` object in the local coordinate space of any other `dst` object:

```
var dst_local_bounds:Rectangle = src.getBounds(dst);
```